# How to solve Apple Mach-o linker error? (_OBJC_CLASS_$_Connection", referenced from..)

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I get this error and people says it about missing frameworks but i can't see I'm missing any.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Connection", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in SocketServer.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It happens when i add this:

```
theServer = [[SocketServer alloc]init];
theServer.serverName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", username];
theServer.delegate = self;
```

What is there to try?

SocketServer is a class from a project from the book Apress Beginning iPhone Games Development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see from the [book's source code](http://www.apress.com/downloadable/download/sample/sample_id/503/), that there is a related `Connection` class that you are forgetting to link with:

```
Beginning iPhone Games Development Source Code/chapter 15 - PartyTime - Peter Bakhirev/TwentyFour final/Classes/Connection.m
```

Add that class to your project and it should then link.

Comment: Big thank you, spent hours on this! Had it in my project but wasn't linked for some reason. Removed it and added it again.